# What aio do i need for the i9 13900k? is my aio failing?

Tags: cpu, cooling, cpu-cooler, water-cooling

My i9 13900k instantly hits 100C with high/meduim load playing games.

My cooler currently is the Corsair 360mm H150i RGB PRO XT but i suspect its on its way out because of the high temps even with fans at 100% at all times.

1. what would be the best aio water cooler that would keep the temps down aka best aio for the i9?(can fit 360mm or 420mm aio)
2. or possibly is my current cooler working correctly but the i9 is just too powerful?

I tried to tilt the radiator to see if there was any air locks but no luck
and I have definitely applied enough thermal paste.

Edit:
the cooling block has been re-seated 3 times and i tightened the screws in a crisscross pattern and each time I removed the cooling block the termal paste shows there was even spread of paste

Edit 2:
with cpu at 100C the coolent after 10 mins of playing it goes from 23C to 27C

you can see when i started to push the CPU(100C) at 100% usage and it lasted 10 minutes
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrwvp.png

Comment: Are you sure the part that goes on the CPU is properly seated?

Comment: the cooling block has been re-seated 3 times and i tightened the screws in a crisscross pattern and each time I removed the cooling block the termal paste shows there was even spread of paste

Comment: 1. Is the **water pump** running at max speed, and effective (i.e., not broken or running **so** fast as to cavitate)? Even with *fans* turning at 2,400 RPM, if the fluid does not get to them, there's insufficient cooling. 2. Check that the system is full, without bubbles.

Comment: Is your current cooler used? The i9 13900k is brand new.  Why do you believe it’s the cooler?

Comment: 1. in icue if the pump is set to extreme(2500) or even balanced(2200 rpm) i get the same temps. 2.i can't check if the system is full because its a closed loop. 3. it is a used cooler but from day of buying it and now it hasn't changed the cooling temps.
it used to run an i5 12600k at 85C when playing games.

Comment: dumb question but it happens - is there a protective plastic film over the waterblock?

Comment: when i re-sat the cooling block i made sure that there was no plastic or other things on the surface. but does 27C max coolant temp after 10 minutes seem right?

Comment: "it is a used cooler, but from the day of buying it" - **YOU KNOW that's not what I meant.**

Comment: Sorry I accidentally miss typed. I bought it from another person and it was used. I meant to say it hasn’t changed how fast or efficiently it cools the cpu from when I bought it to now

Comment: have you found a solution ? I got the same problem

Comment: @JPTétreault i found one thing that helps but is no solution by using intel extreme tuning utility and setting the voltage to 1.25-1.35 because cpu-z says 1.550V and i think the auto voltage is not setting correctly so lowering the voltage helps keep it cooler.
i have no idea why its 1.550V also if i lower the voltage i cant get the clock speed up because it crashes and i assume not enough voltage to the cpu

Comment: Ok tx, in my case, it was a failing MSI AIO apparently, I tried another one and it works now. I get 77c max now but I was getting 90c under minimal load before. Trying to re-apply thermal paste and ensure proper contact between pump and cpu also appears to be key.